# Why is this VBA Code not saving and restoring the Selection correctly

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

I've been trying to use Visual Basic to take every line of text in a Word Document and format it in a certain way depending on the content of the text.

The way I am trying to achieve this is:
1. save the current selection of text
2. find the number of lines in the selection
3. iterate through those lines by selecting one line at a time
4. modifying the line
5. at the end, restore the original selection

I've reduced my code to a minimal example of the issue.

```
Sub ReplaceText()
    ' Save the original selection
    Dim original As range
    Set original = Selection.range

    ' Get the number of lines in the selection
    Dim lines As Long
    With Dialogs(wdDialogToolsWordCount)
        .Execute
        lines = .lines
    End With

    ' Iterate through each line
    For Index = 1 To lines
        ' Go to beginning of line
        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
        ' Select the entire line
        Selection.Expand wdLine
        ' Save the text of the line
        Dim line
        line = Selection.Text

        ' Line with the problem
        ' Just setting the selection text back to itself
        Selection.Text = line

        ' Advance cursor to next Line
        Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine
    Next Index

    ' Restore the original selection
    original.Select
End Sub
```

The issue is that when the original selection is restored at the end, it doesn't restore properly. The restored selection selects everything from the original selection except for the last line. I'm not really sure why this happens.

Edit: After the original.Select, I added the line:

```
Selection.MoveDown Extend:=wdExtend
```

And that seemed to work but it doesn't explain why that happens and how I can prevent the selection from changing.

Comment: What's "the problem" mentioned in the comments, and does the posted code fix it, or is there some code left out here?

Comment: @TimWilliams I am trying to save the user's current selection so that I could restore it later after I changed the text. The problem is that the way I am trying to save and restore it is not working after I add the line with the comment. This is code that is broken and this the smallest example of the issue I can't solve.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Word VBA, but if you capture `Selection.Range.Start` and `.End` positions then you should be able to restore the selection using `ActiveDocument.Range(oStart, oEnd).Select`  However if in your actual use case you're modifying the content then you'd need to track the new end position before restoring the selection

Comment: @TimWilliams I was able to find something that kinda worked, but that still doesn't explain why the selection that's saved in the variable original changed. That's why I'm still confused because it shouldn't change yet it still does.

Comment: It may not be relevant, but when you use Selection.Text to retrieve the text of the Selection, what you are retrieving is the *plain text" of the Selection. If you then set Selection.Text to the text you retrieved, you will lose anything in there that is not plain text - including stuff such as formatting changes etc. (you may not lose *all* the formatting because some of it may have been "set" before the beginning of the text you're selecting).

Comment: You should be aware that lines don't exist in a Word document.  They are an artifact of the Layout (the selected printer) and consequently are only accessible through the Selection object.  You would be much better suited using a range object and paragraphs.

Comment: I concur with others here that you should be using ranges and paragraphs instead of selections and lines. You job will be easier if you paste the paragraphs to a new document instead of trying to replace the text in the source file.

Comment: @TimWilliams This approach is not reliable with Word. The numerical start and end points might not correspond due to hidden control characters in the document. Better would be to add a bookmark to the range/selection that can be addressed at a later point.

Answer (score 0):

It would also help, for such question, to provide sample content and screen shots of the before/after situation - with the display of non-printing characters *on*. `Selection` is very tricky to work with as it always depends on the immediate situation; it's almost impossible to trouble-shoot without the original environment...

That said, your best bet would be to add a ***bookmark*** "around" the selection, which at the end can be selected. The bookmark will be independent of any changes that might be made to the content, so long a it's not deleted. Example:

```
Sub ReplaceText()
    ' Save the original selection
    'Dim original As range
    'Set original = Selection.range
    Dim bkm as Bookmark
    Set bkm = Selection.Bookmarks.Add("temp", Selection.Range)

    ' Get the number of lines in the selection
    Dim lines As Long
    With Dialogs(wdDialogToolsWordCount)
        .Execute
        lines = .lines
    End With

    ' Iterate through each line
''''For...Next removed for the sake of clarity

    ' Restore the original selection
    'original.Select
    bkm.Range.Select
    'Optional: bkm.Delete
End Sub
```